# Sort album list by average rating?

Tags: search, rating, quod-libet

Is there a way to sort Quod Libet’s album list by rating (aggregated by the rating of each track)?

An album with only 5 songs, each with rating 1.0, should come *after* an album with 10 songs, each with rating 1.0.

I can search for `#(rating = 1.0)` in the album list, but this will not take the tracknumber into account.

I can add `<~#rating>` to the shown fields, and this will show me the average rating, but this doesn’t allow me to sort.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - In whichever folder your albums are saved then Right click somewhere -> select Sort By -> More -> select your preferences (there is rating also).

[image]

Comment: Thanks Hunter, but I think this is a misunderstanding: I’m asking how this can be done in [tag:quod-libet] (as I tagged my question).